# Transpose data using Talend

Tags: talend

I have this kind of data:

[image]

I need to transpose this data into something like this using Talend:

[image]

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @ydaetskcoR, any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dbh's suggestion should work indeed, but I did not try it.

However, I have another solution which doesn't require to change input format and is not too complicated to implement. Indeed the job has only 2 transformation components (tDenormalize and tMap).

The job looks like the following:
[image]

**Explanation** :

- Your input is read from a CSV file (could be a database or any other kind of input)
- tDenormalize component will Denormalize your column value (column 2), based on value on id column (column 1), separating fields with a specific delimiter (";" in my case), resulting as shown in 2 rows.
- tMap : split the aggregated column into multiple columns, by using java's String.split() method and spreading the resulting array into multiple columns. The tMap should like like this:
  [image]

Since Talend doesn't accept to store Array objects, make sure to store the splitted String in Object format. Then, cast that object into Array on the right side of the Map.

That approach should give you the expected result.

**IMPORTANT**:

- tNormalize might shuffle the rows, meaning for bigger input, you might encounter unsorted output. Make sure to sort it if needed or use tDenormalizeSortedRow instead.
- tNormalize is similar to an aggregation component meaning it scans the whole input before processing, which results into possible performance issues with particularly big inputs (tens of millions of records).
- Your input is probably wrong (you have 5 entries with 1 as id, and 6 entries with 2 as id). 6 columns are expected meaning you should always have 6 lines per id. If not, then you should implement dbh's solution, and you probably HAVE TO add a column with a key.

Comment: But how can we do if we do not know the number of splitted columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Talend's tPivotToColumnsDelimited  component to achieve this. You will most likely need an additional column in your data to represent the field name.

Like "Identifier, field name, value "

Then you can use this component to pivot the data and write a file as output. If you need to process the data further, read the resulting file with tFileInoutDelimited .

See docs and an example at
https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/13.43+tPivotToColumnsDelimited