# how to transpose columns to rows dynamically talend

Tags: java, transpose, talend

I have to transpose columns into rows in talend.
I've been trying tNormalize, but it doesn't meet my expectations since the process should be running at a single job.

The data looks like this:

```
  ID         |   COLA      |  COLB       | COLC        |
-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
 123WEE      | |800|-90|   |             | 9|7|90      |
 YUTR69      | ||23|       | |99|        | ||-8        |
 KKLOP0      | 1|-77||     | 2           | -789|-443   |
```

The suggested output data:
Hint: Extract everything between delimiters and pass into new rows while the ID follows.
(this includes the null data)

```
  ID         |   COLA      |  COLB       | COLC        |
-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
 123WEE      | 800         |             | 9           |
 123WEE      | -90         |             | 7           |
 123WEE      |             |             | 90          |
 YUTR69      |             | 99          |             |
 YUTR69      | 23          |             | -8          |
 KKLOP0      | 1           | 2           | -789        |
 KKLOP0      | -77         |             | -443        |
 KKLOP0      |             |             |             |
```

What kind of tools I should use and how to write this on tJavaFlex/tJavaRow?

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: did you try tPivot component ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36467131/transpose-data-using-talend

Comment: Yes, I already tried, but it doesn't meet my expectations..